# Result of variables using Semaphore

Tags: java

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore (0);
int x = 7;
int y = 1;

1.1 s.acquire();            2.1 s.release();
                            2.2. s.release();
1.2 s.aquire();             2.3 s.acquire();
1.3 int tmp = x;            2.4 int tmp = y;
1.4 s.release();            2.5 s.release();

1.5. tmp = tmp * 2;         2.6 tmp = tmp * 3;

1.6. s.acquire();           2.7 s.acquire();
1.7 y = tmp + 1;            2.8 x = tmp + 1;
1.8. s.release();           2.9 s.release();
```

[semaphore program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXe8p.png)

I have trouble getting the result of these variables x and y, if these two threads run parallel.

1. The semaphore has 0 permits? So the only possible output here should be x=7, y=1, shouldn't it?
2. I don't understand the nested acquires() and releases(). What would the result of x and y be ifsemaphore would have 2 permits?

Comment: post your code here in text format please

Comment: oh thanks for mentioning, i edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no delays in your code, it can run in many ways, depending on which CPU is faster, or how the OS schedules the threads (e.g. in single-CPU system):

```
                        2.1 s.release();        1 permit
                        2.2 s.release();        2 permits
1.1 s.acquire();                                1 permit
1.2 s.acquire();                                0 permits
1.3 int tmp = x;
1.4 s.release();                                1 permit
1.5 tmp = tmp * 2;
1.6 s.acquire();                                0 permits
1.7 y = tmp + 1;
1.8 s.release();                                1 permit
                        2.3 s.acquire();        0 permits
                        2.4 int tmp = y;
                        2.5 s.release();        1 permit
                        2.6 tmp = tmp * 3;
                        2.7 s.acquire();        0 permits
                        2.8 x = tmp + 1;
                        2.9 s.release();        1 permit
```

Or:

```
                        2.1 s.release();         1 permit
                        2.2 s.release();         2 permits
                        2.3 s.acquire();         1 permit
                        2.4 int tmp = y;
                        2.5 s.release();         2 permits
                        2.6 tmp = tmp * 3;
                        2.7 s.acquire();         1 permit
                        2.8 x = tmp + 1;
                        2.9 s.release();         2 permits
1.1 s.acquire();                                 1 permit
1.2 s.acquire();                                 0 permits
1.3 int tmp = x;
1.4 s.release();                                 1 permit
1.5 tmp = tmp * 2;
1.6 s.acquire();                                 0 permits
1.7 y = tmp + 1;
1.8 s.release();                                 1 permit
```

What **cannot** happen, is for steps 1.3 and 2.4 to run in parallel. There are not enough permits for that.

```
                        2.1 s.release();         1 permit
1.1 s.acquire();                                 0 permits
                        2.2 s.release();         1 permit
1.2 s.acquire();                                 0 permits
1.3 int tmp = x;          <blocked>
1.4 s.release();          <blocked>              1 permit
                        2.3 s.acquire();         0 permits
                        2.4 int tmp = y;
                        2.5 s.release();         1 permit
1.5 tmp = tmp * 2;      2.6 tmp = tmp * 3;
                        2.7 s.acquire();         0 permits
  <blocked>             2.8 x = tmp + 1;
  <blocked>             2.9 s.release();         1 permit
1.6 s.acquire();                                 0 permits
1.7 y = tmp + 1;
1.8 s.release();                                 1 permit
```

There are many other ways these two threads can be interleaved.

Comment: thank you sir that was very helpful. is it possible that there is no output in the end, because threads 1 and 2 are blocked in 1.1 and 1.2 ?

Comment: If thread 1 is blocked in 1.1, then it can't get to 1.2, and thread 2 can run the completion. You're basically describing the second example above, except that there *are* enough permits, so thread 1 wouldn't block.